# Improving classification by using clustering as a feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, knn, gmm

I'm trying to improve my classification results by doing clustering and use the clustered data as another feature (or use it alone instead of all other features - not sure yet).

So let's say that I'm using unsupervised algorithm - GMM:

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=4, random_state=RSEED)

gmm.fit(X_train)

pred_labels = gmm.predict(X_test)
```

I trained the model with training data and predicted the clusters by the test data.

Now I want to use a classifier (KNN for example) and use the clustered data within it. So I tried:

```
#define the model and parameters
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

parameters = {'n_neighbors':[3,5,7],
              'leaf_size':[1,3,5],
              'algorithm':['auto', 'kd_tree'],
              'n_jobs':[-1]}

#Fit the model
model_gmm_knn = GridSearchCV(knn, param_grid=parameters)
model_gmm_knn.fit(pred_labels.reshape(-1, 1),Y_train)

model_gmm_knn.best_params_
```

But I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [418, 891]
```

Train and Test are not with same dimension.
So how can I implement such approach?

Comment: Please think again what you are trying to do in your last `fit`; you are trying to use the cluster features of your test data with the labels of the training data, to do... what exactly? Apart from the obvious dimension mismatch, these labels do not even correspond to the features given.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if my approach is correct at all, but I was asked to try to improve classification results by using unsupervised clustering algorithm and I still don't know how! Based on this example (https://www.kaggle.com/sudeep88/titanic-survivors-classification-using-pca) they used the results of PCA fit as another feature, and used it later for predicting.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.08591.pdf as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not correct - you are attempting to use as a single feature the cluster labels of your *test* data `pred_labels`, in order to fit a classifier with your *training* labels `Y_train`. Even in the huge coincidental case that the dimensions of these datasets were the same (hence not giving a dimension mismatch error, as here), this is conceptually wrong and does not actually make any sense.

What you actually want to do is:

1. Fit a GMM with your training data
2. Use this fitted GMM to get cluster labels for both your training and test data.
3. Append the cluster labels as a new feature in both datasets
4. Fit your classifier with this "enhanced" training data.

All in all, and assuming that your `X_train` and `X_test` are pandas dataframes, here is the procedure:

```
import pandas as pd

gmm.fit(X_train)
cluster_train = gmm.predict(X_train)
cluster_test = gmm.predict(X_test)

X_train['cluster_label'] = pd.Series(cluster_train, index=X_train.index)
X_test['cluster_label'] = pd.Series(cluster_test, index=X_test.index)

model_gmm_knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Notice that you should *not* fit your clustering model with your test data - only with your training ones, otherwise you have data leakage similar to the one encountered when [using the test set for feature selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308116/should-feature-selection-be-done-before-train-test-split-or-after/56548332#56548332), and your results will be both invalid and misleading .

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post with a similar approach before you submitted your answer... but seems that the problem was with appending the feature. Anyway it's working with your code and I'm getting score = 100 (seems weird)

Comment: @M_Z Cool. If you have a follow-up issue, you are always welcome to open a new question. For consistency, I have reverted the question to its previous form (otherwise the answer, which I had already suggested in the comments, looks weird and irrelevant).